# What is the best way to align buttons to the center of a frame using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently I have a `canvas` with a `frame` inside of that deciding the background color and then I have another `frame` inside of that a `frame` aligned to the `center` arbitrarily with the `buttons` inside of that.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
apps = []

if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt', 'r') \
            as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]


def addApp():
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
                                          filetypes=(("executables", "*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
        label.pack()


def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.startfile(app)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="lightblue")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

frameTop = tk.Frame(frame, bg="white")
frameTop.place(width=60, height=70, relx=0.46, rely=0.5)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="grey", command=addApp)
runApp = tk.Button(root, text="Run", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="gray", command=runApps)

runApp.pack()
openFile.pack()

for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()

with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
        f.write(app + ', ')
```

Comment: Note: This is my first time using Tkinter and the Python repository doesn't give much graphical help

Comment: reduce code to important elements and add some example data in code. You don't need `addApp` and `runApps` to align buttons. And you don't need also code after `mainloop()` to align buttons.

Comment: if you want to put frame inside Canvas then you should use `canvas.create_window(pos, Frame(...)` - You don't even use `canvas` as parent for `Frame(canvas, ...)`. Maybe instead of using `Canvas` you should set color on main window `root['bg'] = 'lightblue'`

Comment: if code works then it is the best way.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that puts any widgets inside a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @CloroxBleach and welcome to the Stack Overflow community. Whatever your problem is, whenever you want to put a widget in the center of the window, you use the `.pack()` method. But suppose, when you want to put it sticking to a certain side of the window, then you can use the `anchor` parameter inside `.pack()`. `anchor` can be `N, S, E, W, NE, NW, SE, SW`. `N` puts it on the top while `S`puts it at the bottom and so on. (like the standard order of cardinal directions in a map.)